# Cleaner way to construct a name using Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

This is what I've come up with to construct a name using a javascript object and immutable.js:

```
const getFullName = ({ user }) => {
    if (!user || !user.get('response')) {
        return '';
    }
    return `${user.getIn(['response', 'firstName']) || ''} ${user.getIn(['response', 'lastName']) ||
        ''}`;
};
```

As you can see, it looks pretty ugly. I'm wondering if there is a way to clean this code up. This function is called in loop to show all the names in the dataset. I can imagine that this solution may not be a very `efficient` in such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than repeating `user.getIn(['response'` twice, you can extract the response *once* into a variable. Also, both `.getIn` and `.get` accept a default value if the property isn't found in the collection, which you can use instead of `|| ''`. For example, `.get('foo') || ''` is (existing falsey values aside) equivalent to `.get('foo', '')`.

In up-to-date environments or if the code is being transpiled, you can use optional chaining to more concisely get the nested `response` if it exists.

Since you want to return *something* if one condition is fulfilled, and *something else* otherwise, rather than using `if`, you can make things more concise by using the conditional operator:

```js
const getFullName = ({ user }) => {
    const response = user?.get('response');
    return !response
        ? ''
        : `${response.get('firstName', '')} ${response.get('lastName', '')}`;
};

console.log(getFullName({}));
console.log(getFullName({ user: Immutable.fromJS({}) }));
console.log(getFullName({ user: Immutable.fromJS({ response: { firstName: 'foo' } }) }));
console.log(getFullName({ user: Immutable.fromJS({ response: { firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar' } }) }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```